Postgres upsert with complex logic before update
I'm looking for a method to perform an upsert on a Postgres table but with some complex logic applied to the update based on the existing column value. Essentially I think I need some sort of combination of:
INSERT INTO counts (id, counter) 
VALUES (1, 0)
ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE 
  SET counter = excluded.counter + 1; 

that does a simple upsert and the following SELECT FOR UPDATE synchronization:
// Begin Transaction

curr_count = SELECT counter FROM counts WHERE id = 1 FOR UPDATE; // READ counter but locks rows from concurrent modification

// Perform some complex logic in js on curr_count to determine new_count

UPDATE counts SET counter = new_count WHERE id = 1

// End Transaction

but I don't know how you can you can do the synchronized update only if the insert fails.
I'm using AWS Serverless v2 Postgres but I don't think this makes any difference to the problem.
Thanks!

You don't appear to have any sort of primary key on this counts table and you appear to be thinking curr_count will be a single value. I'm not sure I understand your example.

@RichardHuxton - sorry was trying to create a simple example and obviously failed. I have updated to hopefully be clearer.  counts is the table with an id primary key. The column I want to update based on its existing value is counter. If there is no existing row with id = 1 it should insert one.

Don't you basically just need your top INSERT ... ON CONFLICT but without adding + 1?

But I want to perform some calculation using the current value of counter to determine a new value of counter to then use for the update. While the calculation is happening I need to lock the row to ensure that no concurrent process tries to perform the update at the same time using the original value of counter. The only way I can see to perform this locked update is to use SELECT ... FROM ... FOR UPDATE. Then perform the calculation before finally performing the UPDATE ... SET.

The above works, but I need to ensure that all this only happens if there isn't a unique constraint conflict (i.e. the row doesn't already exist). However, the ON CONFLICT ...  DO UPDATE doesn't seem to allow you to do this type of locked update.
